# How to create a file properly in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

My app was working normally until the simulator changed to iPhone 13, now I'm getting an error when creating files:

```
Future<File> get planDataFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/planData');
}

Future<Plan> createFile() async {
var syncPath = await planDataFile;
    if (!File('$syncPath').existsSync()) {
        new File('$syncPath').createSync();
    }
    // more code
}
```

I tried using the non sync version, doesn't help either.. am I missing something? I also tried using the recursive true flag.

Error logs:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = 'File: '/Users/[user]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/086D31E9-3552-440C-A5D4-134520461353/data/Containers/Data/Application/212EDDC5-E435-45D0-9415-1FE4957DF8F8/Documents/planData'' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
#0 _File.throwIfError (dart:io/file_impl.dart:635:7)
#1 _File.createSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:273:5)
#2 readPlan (package:planner/utils/utils.dart:25:27)
```

Application finished.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sometimes it happens on iOS simulators, did you try restarting the app? also have the current permissions in the runner file?

Comment: I tried restarting the app and the simulator and the laptop.. didn't help.
what do you mean by this:
also have the current permissions in the runner file?